# MySQL Join two records with matching field and creating more columns

Tags: mysql

I cannot figure out how to even explain this succinctly, I suspect there is a word or term for what I want to do but I dont know it. I have a table and it has many duplicate records. each record has 5 columns.

ID (not key), Thing1, Thing2, Thing3.

ID1, ball, ring, jumprope

ID1, flower, book, bell

ID2, something, something

ID3, something, something, something

I would like to do this:

ID1, ball, ring, jumprope, flower, book, bell

ID2, something, something

ID3, something, something, something

Any pointing me to a tutorial would be useful. I just dont even know what to call this to look for a tutorial.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: Your model is likely flawed. See normalisation.

Comment: not my model, but definitely flawed. I will look that up thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if these elements are in seperate tables, you can use JOIN.

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName;
```

in this example they are joining a Customers table with an Orders table, where CustumerID is the same.
[More details](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

Comment: thanks no it a single 40K row table. that looks like I described above.